# GMap library using in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I ma using GMap Google map library in my CodeIgniter application like the follow but when I browse the page it shows the `ReferenceError: onLoadmap is not defined` I don't know what is the problem please help me to fix this problem.

Controller:

```
    $this->load->library("GMap");
    $this->gmap->GoogleMapAPI();
    // valid types are hybrid, satellite, terrain, map
    $this->gmap->setMapType('hybrid');

    $this->gmap->addDirections("Some Street, Some Town, Some City, Some Country", "57 Cardigan Lane, Leeds, UK", 'map_directions', $display_markers=true);

    $this->gmap->disableSidebar();

    $data['headerjs'] = $this->gmap->getHeaderJS();
    $data['headermap'] = $this->gmap->getMapJS();
    $data['onload'] = $this->gmap->printOnLoad();
    $data['sidebar'] = $this->gmap->printSidebar();

    $data['map'] = $this->gmap->printMap();

    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
```

View:

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Map Test</title>
    <?php echo $headerjs; ?>
    <?php echo $headermap; ?>
 </head>
 <body>

<?php echo $onload; ?>
<?php echo $map; ?>
<?php echo $sidebar; ?>
<div id="map_directions"></div>
```

Error:
[image]

The inspect element:
[image]

API Link: https://github.com/gkwelding/GoogleMapsV3CI

Comment: Is `$headerjs` and `$headermap` loaded correctly?

Comment: How should I know loaded correctly or not?

Comment: First check the source in the output, then check the Net-tab in the browser to see that the resources was loaded.

Comment: I edited my question please check my inspect element